# Bash backup script. Read list of files

Tags: macos, bash

Apologies if I'm kind of a bash novice!

I've created a backup script that works fine. However, I want to simplify it a bit, by either reading and inserting a list of files into `rsync` or reading the list of files from another script file into `rsync`.

Reason being so I can easily change the list of files without rewriting the script. As right now I have all the list of files written in each rsync command.

Example:

This is basically what I have written now

```bash
# !/bin/bash
bakdir = ~/backup
mkdir -p $bakdir

mkdir -p "$bakdir"/Documents
cd ~/Documents
rsync -a --progress Document1.doc Document2.doc "$bakdir"/Documents

mkdir -p "$bakdir"/Stuff
cd ~/Stuff
rsync -a --progress Folder1 MyApp.app Document.doc "$bakdir"/Stuff
```

What I want to achieve

```
mkdir -p "$bakdir"/Documents
cd ~/Documents

list1=
Document1.doc
Document2.doc

rsync -a --progress $list1 "$bakdir"/Documents

mkdir -p "$bakdir"/Stuff
cd ~/Stuff

list2=
Folder1
MyApp.app
Document.doc

rsync -a --progress $list2 "$bakdir"/Stuff
```

Tried searching for a question similar to this and can't find anything.

Thank you in advance.

Comment: What's wrong with using Time Machine?

Comment: rsync can be configured to only copy the changes between two locations; is this what you are trying to do?

Comment: I wanted to write a script that automatically backs up and restores files that I choose. It would be a lot faster than individually choosing which files to restore in the Time Machine interface.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Your use of `rsync` seems rather unusual, as suggested it is normal to only allow `rsync` to copy differences.

You could use the option:-

```
--files-from=FILE       read list of source-file names from FILE
```

I have never actually used this (although I use the related `--exclude-from=FILE` option).

Read the `man` page for `rsync`

Comment: I wouldn't be surprised if it was unusual! Thanks for the option, I'll check out the `man`

Answer (score 0):

Put the filenames in an array:

```
list1=("Document1.doc" "Document2.doc")
```

then expand the array:

```
rsync -a --progress "${list1[@]}" "$bakdir"/Documents
```

The reason for using an array rather than a string is so that it will work properly if any of the filenames contain spaces.

Comment: Thanks! I'll try that out.

But what I want to achieve is copying and pasting a files in a list easily without any formatting, such as adding quotes.

Like this:
Folder1
MyApp.app
Document.doc

I can do this by copying the files and pasting into a text editor such as TextMate.

Comment: Ah lost my formatting. What I mean is a list of files like in my example, without changing into one line and adding quotes (this would take a long time with the amount of files I have in the script)

Comment: You can't do a variable assignment on multiple lines like that. Each line is a separate command.

Comment: You should be able to change it using a regular expression replacement in an editor.

Answer (score 0):

Store the file names in a text file (ie "mydata.txt") with the format:

```
Documents Document1.doc Document2.doc
Stuff Folder1 MyApp.txt
```

and execute following script (myscript):

```
while read d fs; do
  cd ~/$d
  mkdir ~/backup/$d
  rsync ... $fs
done
```

use $d for the directory, $fs for the file list, arguments of mkdir, rsync, ... like in your question.

Execution command line is:

```
myscript < mydata.txt
```